# PowerShell Function using ParamSets with a for loop

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

I put together a powershell function that schedules server reboots.

I'm stuck on adding a `for loop` to run the function for multiple servers using ParameterSetName.

Before adding the ParamSets, I just setup a function and called the function in the same script within a `for` loop which worked great.

```
Function ScheduleReboot{
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true,DefaultParameterSetName="ViewOnly")]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="KillSwitch")]
    [Switch]$NukeJobs,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
    HelpMessage="ServerName goes here",ParameterSetName="FullRun")]
    [string]$server,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
        HelpMessage="Enter a Date/Time 07-28-15 16:00 For July 28th, 2015 at 4:00 PM",
        ParameterSetName="FullRun"
    )]
    [ValidatePattern('(?#Enter MM-dd-YY HH:MM 24hr clock)\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}[:]\d{2}')]
    $date,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="ViewOnly")]
    [switch]$ViewOnly

) #"$server will reboot on $date"

    Switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName){
        "KillSwitch"{
            if($env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE -eq "x86")
            {
                set-alias ps64 "$env:windir\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
                $script2 = [ScriptBlock]::Create("IF(Test-Path -Path C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs\$server) 
                {Remove-Item -Force -Path C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs\$server}")
                "Removing previous scheduled server reboot data"
                ps64 -command $script2
            } else {
                Get-ScheduledJob | Unregister-ScheduledJob
            }
        }#End killswitch block.

        "FullRun" {
            [array]$servers = gc D:\Scripts\servers.txt
            [array]$dates = gc D:\Scripts\dates.txt
            if($dates.Length -eq $servers.Length)
            {
                "Input count matches"
                for($i=0;$i -lt $servers.Length;$i++)
                {
                    $day =  $dates[$i]
                    $comp = $servers[$i]
                    $user = Get-Credential -UserName $env:USERNAME -Message "UserName/password for scheduled Reboot"
                    $trigger = New-JobTrigger -once -at $day
                    $script = [ScriptBlock]::Create("D:\Scripts\Scheduled-Reboot-Single.ps1 -server $server | Out-File -Force \\SysLogSvr\d$\scripts\$server-Reboot.log")
                    Register-ScheduledJob -Name $comp -Credential $user -Trigger $trigger -ScriptBlock $script
                }#end for loop
            } else {
                $warn = "Server list contains " + $servers.Count + " items and Date list contains " + $dates.Count + " items, Please re-check!!!"
                Write-Warning $warn
            }
        }#end fullrun block.

        "ViewOnly" {
            Get-ScheduledJob | Get-JobTrigger
            Get-ScheduledJob | Select Name,Command | FT -AutoSize
        }#end viewonly block.
    }#End param switch
}#end function.
```

Comment: `Before adding the ParamSets, I just setup a function and called the function in the same script within a for loop which worked great.` and why can't you still do that? Alternatively, you can make server accept an array `[String[]]` and/or accept its value from pipeline `[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]` and use a `process{}` block.

Comment: I was thinking about using Begin/Process/End but wasn't sure that was the most efficient method.  Thank  you, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @user4317867 "efficient" in terms of what? You'll have to process a *large* number of servers (millions) before the overhead from begin/process/end will start to become noticeable in terms of execution time

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I'm just unsure how to wrap all that up but I'll work on this tomorrow.

Comment: @briantist because I'm not quite sure how to incorporate a loop in a function with paramsets.  Before the paramsets, the loop just performed a function call for each item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make that 3 (or more) different functions. The parameter sets the way you are using it is over-complicating it and making it hard for you to debug it.

I would have made a `Get-ScheduledReboot`, `Clear-ScheduledReboot`, `Set-ScheduledReboot` collection of functions.

There are a few bugs in this script as posted that are causing you issues. The first is the nuke parameter set does not contain the server parameter. The other bug is the one that is throwing you off. You define a $server parameter above but in the function, you change gears and load from a text file. You are mixing `$server`, `$servers` and `$comp` variables around causing it to fail.

You should change your `[string]$server` to `[string[]]$server` or better yet, `[string[]$ComputerName` and `foreach($node in $ComputerName){...}` on the collection. Keep the text file loading outside that function.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I'll admit I've been putting these scripts together without very much PowerShell knowledge.  I'm working on cleaning it up for general use.